# Recursive Confusion

Tags: c, function, recursion

Hello everyone I had a tough time understanding recursive function calls and just when I thought I have understood them, I saw a question which made me realized that I am wrong 
I am not able to understand the flow of the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int n)
{   
    if(n>0)
    {   
        fun(--n);
        printf("%d\n",n);
        fun(--n);
    }
}   
int main(void) {
    int a;
    a=3;
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Explain the flow of the program

Comment: Does replacing `fun(--n);` with `--n; fun(n);` help you ?

Comment: No it doesn't I am thinking about the einpoklum answer though that arguments are passed by value but still I am unable to get the flolw

Comment: @RohitSaluja - using a debugger will be priceless for you in this case - you will be able to follow the execution step by step, watching the value of `n` and the calls flow. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to understand it with case `n=2` and then you should be able to generalize.

```
fun (2):
```

What happens inside (flow):

1) `n=2:` `if(n>0)` is true and `fun(--n)` is called with `n` set to value 1 due to --; (see step below).

2) `n=1:` Now `n=1`: again `if(n>0)` is true and `fun(--n)` is called with `n=0`. See step below.

3) `n=0:` Now `n=0;` `if(n>0)` is false, so we return.

I think here is your confusion. From step 3 you **are thrown back**
at **step 2** (**not step 1**). You are thrown actually in step 2 after `fun(--n)` call - so `printf` is called with value of `n=0`, due to decrement.
Then again in same place (after `printf`) `fun(--n)` is called with value `n=-1` however, which will also exit - and eventually you will be thrown at the beginning.

Comment: Yes from step 3 we are returned to step 2 and the control comes now to printf() statement which is printing the value of n so step 3 returned void and the value of n at step 2 is 1 which is were we are currently so shouldn't 1 get printed instead of 0

Comment: @RohitSaluja ,`n` has already been decremented as you use the prefix decrement operator.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function call for your function when n = 3

```
f(3)
.f(2) [1]
..f(1) [1]
...f(0) [1]
...Print 0
...f(-1) [2]
..Print 1
..f(0) [2]
.Print 2
.f(1) [2]
..f(0) [1]
..Print 0
..f(-1)[2]
```

Where `.` represent the depth of stack and 1 and 2 specify whether its first recursive call from the loop or second.

Because

```
f(3)
```

becomes

```
f(2)
print 2
f(1)
```

which inturn becomes

```
f(1)
print 1
f(0)
print 2
f(0)
print 0
f(-1)
```

Which finally becomes

```
f(0)
print 0
f(-1)
print 1
f(0)
print 2
f(0)
print 0
f(-1)
```

Removing all the `f(n)` when `n <= 0`

```
print 0
print 1
print 2
print 0
```

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, and I respected that condition. It prints 0 after calling `f(0)` first time, isn;t it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cause of confusion is your assumption that the same "n" is used by every call to the function `fun()`. In fact, that's not the case, since in the C language, argument are passed by value. That is, when `fun(3)` calls `fun(2)`, a new `n` is created - specific to one instance of `fun(2)`. Thus after the call to `fun(3)` within `fun(2)`, the value of `n` is 2, not or -1.

You should therefore expect...

fun(1) to print 0
fun(2) to print 1
fun(3) to print 2
fun(1) (called from the second call to fun(2)) to print 0

and that's it.

Comment: @tobi303: umm, sorry, yeah. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a "call tree" to help visualize the program.

The function has those parts

```
decrement n, call, print, decrement n, call
```

now you can draw this:

```
                  0                 -1
            1->0,   print 0, 0->-1,                   0
      2->1,                            print 1, 1->0,                 1->0, .....
3->2,                                                   print 2, 2->1, .....
```

Start at the bottom left, and go up one line for each call. The program executes from left to right, and you can clearly see the order of the numbers printed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens (pseudocode):

```
   n = 3
   fun(3);
      n = 2
      fun(2); // first fun(--n)
         n = 1
         fun(1); // first fun(--n)
            n = 0
            fun(0); // first fun(--n)
               return;
            print 0
            n = -1
            fun(-1); // second fun(--n)
               return;
            return;
         print 1
         n = 0
         fun(0); // second fun(--n)
            return;
         return;
      print 2
      n = 1
      fun(1); // second fun(--n)
         n = 0
         fun(0); // first fun(--n)
            return;
         print 0
         n = -1
         fun(-1); // second fun(--n)
            return;
         return;
      return;
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the program can be understood by iteratively expanding the function calls and removing the conditions; in a pseudocode-manner, this can be done as follows.

```
fun(3)
```

Can be expanded to the following.

```
if(3>0)
{   
    fun(2);
    printf("%d\n",2);
    fun(1);
}
```

In the follwing steps, the `if` condition is omitted if it will evaluate to false.

```
fun(1);
printf("%d\n",1);
fun(0);
printf("%d\n",2);
fun(0);
printf("%d\n",0);
fun(-1);
```

The calls to `fun` with non-positive arguments can be omitted as they will generate no output.

```
fun(1);
printf("%d\n",1);
printf("%d\n",2);
printf("%d\n",0);
```

Further expansion yields the following sequence.

```
fun(0);
printf("%d\n",0);
fun(-1);
printf("%d\n",1);
printf("%d\n",2);
printf("%d\n",0);
```

This can be again reduced to the following sequence.

```
printf("%d\n",0);
printf("%d\n",1);
printf("%d\n",2);
printf("%d\n",0);
```

So in total, the output will be as follows.

```
0
1
2
0
```

I hope this answers your question; however, it does not provide an intuitive way of describing the generated output.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the recursive flow you can instrument your code with few printfs like below. This will show the sequence of flow of function using indentation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSpace(int num)
{
    while(num > 0)
    {
        printf(" ");
        num--;
    }
}

int NumSpace = 0;
void fun(int n)
{   
    printSpace(NumSpace);
    printf("fun(%d)\n", n);
    NumSpace += 4;
    if(n>0)
    {   
        fun(--n);
        printSpace(NumSpace);
        printf("%d\n",n);
        fun(--n);
    }
    NumSpace -= 4;
}   
int main(void) {
    int a;
    a=3;
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}


Result:
fun(3)
    fun(2)
        fun(1)
            fun(0)
            0
            fun(-1)
        1
        fun(0)
    2
    fun(1)
        fun(0)
        0
        fun(-1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would move `NumSpace += 4;` up to be the first statement in `fun()`. Because for example, the first `0` is printed by `fun(1)` and not by `fun(0)`.